# В чем разница между InnoDB и MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

В чем разница между движками MySQL - InnoDB и MyISAM? Каковы их слабые и сильные стороны?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- MyISAM поддерживает сжатие таблиц в отличии от InnoDB.
- MyISAM имеет встроенные полнотекстный поиск в отличии от InnoDB.
- InnoDB поддерживает транзакции в отличии от MyISAM.
- InnoDB поддерживает блокировки уровня строки (MyISAM - только уровня таблицы).
- InnoDB поддерживает ограничения внешних ключей (MyISAM - нет).
- InnoDB более надежна при больших объемах данных.
- InnoDB в теории немного быстрее.

Comment: Добавлю, InnoDB поддерживает внешние ключи.
> InnoDB в теории немного быстрее
С чего ты это взял?

Comment: В версии сервера MySQL 3.23.44 и выше таблицы InnoDB поддерживают проверку ограничений внешних ключей.

Answer (score 1):

До недавнего времени **InnoDB** не поддерживала полнотекстовые индексы.
InnoDB не хранит ни количество строк в таблице, ни следующее значение автоинкрементного поля. Первое не так важно, поскольку мало кому бывает нужно считать все строки в таблице, без какого бы то ни было фильтра.
А вот второе в теории чревато. Если после удаления последнего выданного id сервер будет перегружен, то id будет выделен повторно. Впрочем, я не слышал о случавшихся такого рода косяках на практике

Answer (score 0):

Есть один очевидный (но не сразу) минус MyISAM, вытекающий из особенностей блокировок. Если в системе могут выполняться тяжелые SELECTы, то любой UPDATE на участвующие в нем таблицы будет ждать окончания SELECTа и блочить все дальнейшие запросы. Если с базой работают достаточно активно, то это не вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Главное в InnoDB это блокировки по строкам, что соответствует логике архитектуры при которой субъектом данных является именно строка. Нарушение этой логики приводит к непредсказуемым последствиям. Например, если приложение имеет собственный порядок исполнения и в этом порядке есть работа с базой данных, то порядок работы приложения может вступить в конфликт с порядком организации данных в MyISAM. И будет так называемый Deadlock: часть приложения ждет другую часть, а другая часть ждет данных в базе заблокированных первой частью приложения.

Answer (score -3):

Если коротко, то в `InnoDB` есть поддержка транзакций, а у `MyISAM` нету.
И еще `MyISAM` в отличие от `InnoDB` поддерживает текстовую индексацию.
В основном используется `MyISAM`.