# MyISAM или InnoDB? Интернет-магазин

Tags: php, mysql

Какой движок лучше выбрать для интернет-магазина, если заносится в `БД` будет абсолютно каждый шаг пользователя, вплоть до нажатия галочки `remember me` при авторизации. Правда для таких данных я наверное буду использовать тип таблицы `ARCHIVE`, или этот тип таблицы не использовать?

Также планирую записывать каждое нажатие пользователя, на ссылку, блок и т.д., т.е. каждое нажатие на ссылку и блок будут отправлять данные на сервер в фоне при помощи `AJAX`.

Да, я знаю, есть метрика, аналитикс и т.д. Но всё же с какими проблема я могу столкнуться?

**VPS:** 512MB, SSD, 1 ядро Xeon E5-2650 v3 2.3GHz, KVM и `Debian 8`

Comment: @Mike мой вопрос более расширенный, и да, этот я видел, статью читал, ничего нового не узнал, надеюсь здесь услышать чего то нового)

Comment: ничего нового не услышите. это бесконечные споры, что лучше. Как по мне, раз магазин, значит работа с деньгами, раз деньги - требуются транзакции.

Comment: а я так старался расписать обширнее...в общем, спасибо

Comment: да и движок от силы 5% производительности. а 80% - это грамотная структура БД и запросы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/58156/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-innodb-%d0%b8-myisam